# js code to tell if a function is available for an object

Tags: javascript

The following line of javascript gets a Uncaught TypeError: **Object #Text has no method 'getAttribute'** in chrome and safari but not in IE.

```
this.Element.getAttribute("whatever")
```

I get that this.Element is the main problem, but would like a temporary fix for debugging other parts of the code. **How can test to see if a function is available on an item without getting a javascript error?**

Comment: you could wrap it in a try/catch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (this.Element.getAttribute)
{
// exists
}
else
{
// does not
}
```

Comment: And what if `this.Element.getAttribute` is a boolean?  Or anything other than a function?

Comment: @ScottSauyet look, all the OP wanted was to test if the .getattribute() existed for this object.This will work as long as this.Element is an object. And if a coder names a boolean as getAttribute, he shouldnt be coding :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (this && this.Element && typeof this.Element.getAttribute == "function") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: See @Jaspers answer. checking if it is undefined would prevent you from having to check `this` and `this.element`

Comment: @Bot: No, instead if you skip these checks and Element was not defined, the JS engine would throw a TypeError, something like "Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined